# Google Treemap: want to put color of node in red, green and amber

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

I am using Google Treemap to show department wise data. I am not being able to set the color of nodes in which I want. I don't know whether colors are decided by treemap itself.

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['treemap'], callback: drawVisualization});
function drawVisualization() {
    // Create and populate the data table.
    var dataArray = [];
    dataArray.push(['Department Name', 'Parent', 'Number of Goals', 'color']);
    dataArray.push(['Goals by Team', null, 0, 0]);
    dataArray.push(['Sales', 'Goals by Team', 2, 'red']);
    dataArray.push(['Finance', 'Goals by Team', 6, 'green']);
    dataArray.push(['Pre-Sales', 'Goals by Team', 8, 'red']);
    dataArray.push(['Technology', 'Goals by Team', 4, 'amber']);
    dataArray.push(['Management', 'Goals by Team', 1, 'amber']);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var treemap = new google.visualization.TreeMap(document.getElementById('visualization'));
    treemap.draw(data, {
    minColor: 'red',
    midColor: 'orange',
    maxColor: 'green',
    headerHeight: 0,
    fontColor: 'black',
    showScale: true});

    google.visualization.events.addListener(treemap, 'select', showGoalsByDepartment);
    google.visualization.events.trigger(treemap, 'select', null);
    function showGoalsByDepartment() {
    var selection = treemap.getSelection();
    if (selection && selection.length > 0) {
        var node_name = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
        $location.path('departmentGoal/'+node_name);
        $scope.$apply();
    }
    }
}
```

But the colors of nodes are not being shown as assigned.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

colors for the treemap are assigned on a gradient scale,
there are no standard options that will allow assignment of a specific color to each node.

however, the chart can be modified manually, after it has been drawn.

---

**first**, the last color column in the data table should be a number,
this is what the treemap uses to determine the value of the gradient color.
the treemap will throw an error if a string is used.

as such, we will use a data view to exclude this column when drawing the chart.

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);
```

---

**next**, when the chart is drawn, `<rect>` elements are used to draw each node,
along with a `<text>` element for the label.
both elements will be stored in a `<g>` element, similar to the following.

```
<g style="cursor: default;">
  <rect x="5" y="0" width="480" height="195" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="1" fill="Red"></rect>
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="245" y="101.7" font-family="Arial" font-size="12" stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#000000">Pre-Sales</text>
</g>
```

in order to assign our specific color, we loop through all the `<rect>` elements,
for each `<rect>` we find the associated `<text>` label,
then go back to the original data table and find the row with that label using `getFilteredRows`.
then we can pull the color from that row, and assign it to the `<rect>`.

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
  var textElements = rect.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text');
  if (textElements.length > 0) {
    var dataRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
      column: 0,
      value: textElements[0].textContent
    }]);
    if (dataRows.length > 0) {
      rect.setAttribute('fill', data.getValue(dataRows[0], 3));
    }
  }
});
```

---

**finally**, the chart will change our color back to the default gradient anytime there is activity, such as `'select'`.
to override, we can use a `MutationObserver`.

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(addColors);
observer.observe(container, {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});
```

---

**see following working snippet**

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages:['treemap'], callback: drawVisualization});
function drawVisualization() {
  var dataArray = [];
  dataArray.push(['Department Name', 'Parent', 'Number of Goals', 'color']);
  dataArray.push(['Goals by Team', null, 0, null]);
  dataArray.push(['Sales', 'Goals by Team', 2, 'Red']);
  dataArray.push(['Finance', 'Goals by Team', 6, 'Green']);
  dataArray.push(['Pre-Sales', 'Goals by Team', 8, 'Red']);
  dataArray.push(['Technology', 'Goals by Team', 4, 'OrangeRed']);
  dataArray.push(['Management', 'Goals by Team', 1, 'OrangeRed']);

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataArray);
  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2]);

  var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
  var treemap = new google.visualization.TreeMap(container);

  var observer = new MutationObserver(addColors);
  observer.observe(container, {
    childList: true,
    subtree: true
  });

  function addColors() {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(container.getElementsByTagName('rect'), function(rect) {
      var textElements = rect.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text');
      if (textElements.length > 0) {
        var dataRows = data.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 0,
          value: textElements[0].textContent
        }]);
        if (dataRows.length > 0) {
          rect.setAttribute('fill', data.getValue(dataRows[0], 3));
        }
      }
    });
  }

  google.visualization.events.addListener(treemap, 'select', showGoalsByDepartment);
  google.visualization.events.trigger(treemap, 'select', null);
  function showGoalsByDepartment() {
    var selection = treemap.getSelection();
    if (selection && selection.length > 0) {
      var node_name = data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0);
      //$location.path('departmentGoal/'+node_name);
      //$scope.$apply();
    }
  }

  treemap.draw(view, {
    showScale: false,
    headerHeight: 0,
    fontColor: 'black'
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="visualization"></div>
```

---

**notes**

**1)** the script library `jsapi` should no longer be used.

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

see the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/release_notes)...

> The version of Google Charts that remains available via the jsapi loader is no longer being updated consistently. Please use the new gstatic `loader.js` from now on.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

this will only change the `load` statement, see snippet above.

**2)** event listeners, such as `'select'`, should be assigned **before** the chart is drawn.

**3)** `Amber` is not a valid [html color name](https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_names.asp), `OrangeRed` was used above instead.

**4)** the color scale was removed in the above snippet, since it will not match our specific color assignment.

```
showScale: false
```